# Axios returning pending promise

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I have been searching for an answer for 3 days, so, I finally decided to ask by myself.
I am using Nuxt JS and Riot API, and am new to both of them. I want to get data, then return it to store it inside another variable I could use later on. When I try to console log the data directly from inside my function, it works and I can see the data I want. But when I try to return it, it gives me this answer

[image: returned console log]

Here is my function

```js
mounted() {
  console.log(this.fetchSomething())
},

methods: {
    async fetchSomething() {
        const test = await this.$axios.get('/api/')
        .then((res) => {
            return res.data;
        })
        console.log(test) // this works
        return test // this gives me a pending promise
        
    },
}
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to jfriend00 for his amazing answer, correcting my code but most importantly explaining me what was wrong. I have now a better understanding of my mistake.

Corrected code

```
async mounted() {
  const gettest = await this.fetchSomething()
  console.log(gettest)
},

methods: {
  async fetchSomething() {
            const test = await this.$axios.get('/api/');
            //console.log(test.data);
            return test.data;            
        },
},
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All `async` function return a promise.  The return value inside the `async` function becomes the resolved value of that returned promise.  If there is an `await` inside the `async` function, then the function returns a promise as soon as the interpreter encounters the first `await` in the function.  If there are not `await` statements in the function, it still returns a promise that will be immediately resolved with whatever your return value is.

Keep in mind that `await` suspends internal execution of the `async` function.  It does not stop the caller's execution.  At that first `await`, the caller gets a pending promise and the caller keeps executing.  The caller MUST use `await` or `.then()` themselves to get the return value from an `async` function.

Here's what happens inside your `async` function step-by-step"

1. You call `this.fetchSomething()`.
2. As that starts to execute, the `this.$axios.get('/api/')` is executed and it returns a promise and then the interpreter processes the `await thatPromise`.  At that first `await`, the function execution is suspended and the function immediately returns an unresolved and pending promise.
3. Your `console.log()` sees that pending promise as the function has now returned
4. Some time later, the `axios.get().then(...)` finishes and resolves the promise it returns so the `await` is done and assigned the resolved value of that `axios.get().then()` promise to your variable `test`.  The value in `test` is the result of your return value in `.then()`
5. Finally, you log the value of `test` and then you return the value of `test`.
6. That return value becomes the resolved value of the promise that was already returned from the `async` function and that promise then gets resolved with that value.

If you look carefully at your two `console.log()` statements, you will see that this one `console.log(this.fetchSomething())` happens first because that's where the function hit the `await` and then immediately returned the pending promise.  Your second `console.log(test)` happens later after the `await` is done waiting for the axios promise.

FYI, many people prefer not to mix `await` and `.then()` (though this doesn't change the outcome you were asking about - it's just a style issue) and you could write your function like this:

```
methods: {
    async fetchSomething() {
        const test = await this.$axios.get('/api/');
        console.log(test.data);
        return test.data;            
    },
}
```

or, even this:

```
methods: {
    async fetchSomething() {
        const {data} = await this.$axios.get('/api/');
        console.log(data);
        return data;            
    },
}
```